# Plotting savings rate in Go

Tags: beginner, csv, go, finance, data-visualization

I'm picking up Go, and wrote this simple script to parse a two csv files (spending.csv and savings.csv) to plot savings rate graph.

I would like to hear some generic comments on code readability, libraries I missed out on using, and Go-ness of the code I wrote.

I also used global variable `months` which I am not very happy about, but I could not find another way to get to the variable from `(monthTicks)` function which overrides `plot.Ticks`. Any advise on making this prettier is welcome.

Also, I did not use `csv` library, nor did I parse the command line arguments - these are two improvements I am aware of.

```
/*
Plot a savings rate graph using income and spending data exported from mint.com.

This script relies on spending.csv and income.csv being present in the same
directory, and produces savings.png image.
*/
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gonum/plot"
    "github.com/gonum/plot/plotter"
    "github.com/gonum/plot/plotutil"
    "github.com/gonum/plot/vg"
)

var BEFORE_MAX int = 6
var AFTER_MAX int = 6
var TICK_INTERVAL int = 2

var months []string // TODO: Figure out how to pass this to monthTicks.

func main() {
    var income_amounts []float64
    months, income_amounts = processFile("income.csv")
    _, spending_amounts := processFile("spending.csv")

    savings_rates := calculateSavingsRates(income_amounts, spending_amounts)

    drawAndSavePlot(savings_rates, "savings.png")
}

// Do the math and build a list of savings rate with a
// BEFORE_MAX/AFTER_MAX-moving average. The formula for savings rate is (money
// earned - money spent) / money earned.
func calculateSavingsRates(income_amounts, spending_amounts []float64) []float64 {
    var savings_rates, moving_average_rates []float64

    for i := range months {
        earned, spent := income_amounts[i], spending_amounts[i]
        savings_rates = append(savings_rates, (earned-spent)/earned)
    }

    for i := range savings_rates {
        before, after := i-BEFORE_MAX, i+AFTER_MAX
        if before < 0 {
            before = 0
        }
        if after > len(savings_rates)-1 {
            after = len(savings_rates) - 1
        }
        var window_sum float64
        for k := before; k < after; k++ {
            window_sum += savings_rates[k]
        }
        moving_average_rates = append(
            moving_average_rates, window_sum/float64(after-before))
    }
    return moving_average_rates
}

// Create and save a plot of savings rates over time.
func drawAndSavePlot(savings_rates []float64, save_filename string) {
    savings_plot, err := plot.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    savings_plot.Title.Text = "Plot of savings rate over time"
    savings_plot.X.Label.Text = "Time"
    savings_plot.X.Tick.Marker = monthTicks{}
    savings_plot.Y.Label.Text = "Savings rate"
    plot_points := preparePlotPoints(savings_rates)
    err = plotutil.AddLinePoints(savings_plot, plot_points)

    err = savings_plot.Save(10*vg.Inch, 10*vg.Inch, save_filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type monthTicks struct{}

// Verbal month/year (e.g. "Mar 2016") tick labels for the plot. Ticks appears
// every TICK_INTERVAL months.
func (monthTicks) Ticks(min, max float64) []plot.Tick {
    var ticks []plot.Tick
    for i, month := range months {
        if i%TICK_INTERVAL != 0 {
            continue
        }
        split := strings.Split(month, " ")
        month_, year := split[0], split[1]
        month = strings.Join([]string{month_[:3], year}, " ")

        ticks = append(ticks, plot.Tick{Value: float64(i), Label: month})
    }
    return ticks
}

// Create plot points with integers 0..len(savings_rates) on X axis, and a
// given rate plot on Y axis.
func preparePlotPoints(savings_rates []float64) plotter.XYs {
    points := make(plotter.XYs, len(savings_rates))
    for i, rate := range savings_rates {
        points[i].X = float64(i)
        points[i].Y = rate
    }
    return points
}

// Load and parse given csv file, returning a list of first column values
// (months) and a list of second column values ($ amount). First line (headers)
// and last line (totals) are not returned.
func processFile(filename string) ([]string, []float64) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var months []string
    var amounts []float64

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text := strings.Replace(scanner.Text(), "\"", "", -1)
        text = strings.Replace(text, "$", "", -1)
        var split []string = strings.Split(text, ",")
        month := split[0]
        if month == "Dates" || month == "Total" { // Ignore first/last columns.
            continue
        }

        amount, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.Join(split[1:], ""), 64)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        months = append(months, month)
        amounts = append(amounts, amount)
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return months, amounts
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some high-level comments after one pass on your code:

- [Don't panic.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic) Handle errors instead; and use `log.Fatalf` at the highest level.
- [Don't use underscores in variable names.](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps) Your variable names are also a bit too long.
- Declare your variables in one block, don't declare their type unless needed:

  ```
  var (
       beforeMax = 6
       afterMax = 6
       …
  )
  ```

  See also `var split []string = strings.Split(text, ",")` that should be rewritten `split := strings.Split(text, ",")`.
- To get your `month` variable from `monthTicks`, add it into the struct:

  ```
  type monthTicks struct{
      months []string
  }
  ```

  and initialize it with:

  ```
  savingsPlot.X.Tick.Marker = &monthTicks{months}
  ```

  the Ticks function becomes:

  ```
  func (mt *monthTicks) Ticks(min, max float64) []plot.Tick {
      var ticks []plot.Tick
      for i, month := range mt.months {
          …
      }
      …
  }
  ```
- Not using command-line flags for a small script for simplicity's sake is questionable, but why not. There's really no excuse for not using the `csv` package, though — you're making your job significantly more difficult and I'm pretty sure a malformed input could break your code in various ways.
- `Scanner.Scan` will fail if your lines are too long. Something to be aware of =)